# How to take user input as function input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make my function take an name from the user which would check if the name is in a whitelist before executing a function that prints draws out information from a pre-defined list of the same name but the entered input is being processed as a string by the function instead of the name of the list. How do I get it to take in the input as the name of the list?

```
hydrogen = ["Hydrogen", "H", "1", "1.0"]
helium = ["Helium", "He", "2", "4.0"]

universe = ["hydrogen", "helium"]

elementname_print = "Element Name: "
elementsymbol_print = "Element Symbol: "
atomicnumber_print = "Atomic Number: "
relativeatomicmass_print = "Relative Atomic Mass: "

def printelement(element):
  print(f" \n-------------------------")
  print(elementname_print + element[0])
  print(elementsymbol_print + element[1])
  print(atomicnumber_print + element[2])
  print(relativeatomicmass_print + element[3])
  print("-------------------------")

userinput = input("-->")
if userinput in universe:
  printelement(userinput)
else:
  print("Sorry that element cannot be found.")
```

Result:

--> hydrogen

Element Name: h

Element Symbol: y

Atomic Number: d

Relative Atomic Mass: r

Comment: Define them using a dictionary with keys being the strings that you want the user to use and the values being the list(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, rather than defining your elements in global scope as `hydrogen = ...`, define them inside a dictionary keyed by their name.

```
elements = {"hydrogen": ["Hydrogen", "H", "1", "1.0"],
            "helium": ["Helium", "He", "2", "4.0"]}
```

the lookup then becomes much easier.

```
def print_element(element_name):
    element = elements[element_name]
    # the rest as written
```

Note that you can clean up your code quite a bit:

```
elements = {"hydrogen": ["Hydrogen", "H", "1", "1.0"],
            "helium": ["Helium", "He", "2", "4.0"]}

def print_element(element_name):
    element = elements[element_name]
    name, symbol, number, mass = element

    print(f"""
----------------------
Element Name:         {name}
Element Symbol:       {symbol}
Atomic Number:        {number}
Relative Atomic Mass: {mass}
----------------------""")

userinput = input("-->")
if userinput in elements:
    print_element(userinput)
else:
    print("Sorry that element cannot be found.")
```

---

There are ways to make your chosen solution work (`eval` will do it, but introduce huge security risks. `globals()` will do it, but introduce a large performance overhead), but they're all ugly. Writing an ugly hack is objectively worse than using the right approach in the first place

Comment: Exactly, use a dict.

Comment: @Adam, Nice and precise answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith, i see there is mistake in  writing function name in the `printelement(userinput)` section it should be rather `print_element(userinput)`  .. i see a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can eval the string input to the corresponding variable :

```
printelement(eval(userinput))
```

Rest code remains the same.

P.S : This is a quick hack, using eval is unsafe.

Comment: this is mega unsafe.

Comment: @AdamSmith, yes, indeed. Edited to note it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your need to get a list corresponding to the user input. Use `globals()`:

```
  lst = globals()[userinput]
```

So in your example, if user types in `'hydrogen'`, this will give the list `hydrogen`. Now do your printings.

**Complete example**:

```
hydrogen = ["Hydrogen", "H", "1", "1.0"]
helium = ["Helium", "He", "2", "4.0"]
universe = ["hydrogen", "helium"]

elementname_print = "Element Name: "
elementsymbol_print = "Element Symbol: "
atomicnumber_print = "Atomic Number: "
relativeatomicmass_print = "Relative Atomic Mass: "

def printelement(element):
  print(f" \n-------------------------")
  print(elementname_print + element[0])
  print(elementsymbol_print + element[1])
  print(atomicnumber_print + element[2])
  print(relativeatomicmass_print + element[3])
  print("-------------------------")

userinput = input("-->")
if userinput in universe:
  lst = globals()[userinput]
  printelement(lst)
else:
  print("Sorry that element cannot be found.")
```